# Select all and Select None buttons in Autocomplete Material UI React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to implement two buttons Select All and Select None inside Autocomplete React Material UI along with checkbox for each option.When Select All button is clicked all the options must be checked and when I click Select None all the options must be unchecked.
How do I implement that ?

```
<Autocomplete
      id={id }
      size={size}
      multiple={multiple}
      value={value}
      disabled={disabled}
      options={items}
      onChange={handleChange}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.label}
      renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
        <React.Fragment >
          {isCheckBox(check, selected)}
          {option.label}
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField id="dropdown_input"
          {...params} label="controlled" variant={variant} label={label} placeholder={placeholder} />
      )}
    />
export function isCheckBox(check, selected) { 
  if (check) {
    const CheckBox = <Checkbox
      id="dropdown_check"
      icon={icon}
      checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
      checked={selected}
    />
    return CheckBox;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I stumbled into the same issue earlier today.
The trick is to use local state to manage what has been selected, and change the renderOption to select * checkboxes if the local state has the 'all' key in it.

NB: At the time of writing React 16 is what I'm working with
I'm on a deadline, so I'll leave a codesandbox solution for you instead of a rushed explanation. Hope it helps :
[Select All AutoComplete Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-kznv3?file=/demo.js)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make an autocomplete with select all option using react material ui and react hook form, you can implement to Autocomplete like so

- `multiple`: To allow multiple selection
- `disableCloseOnSelect`: To disable the close of the box after each selection
- `options`: Array of items of selection
- `value`: Selected options.
- `getOptionLabel`: The string value of the option in our case is `name`
- `filterOptions`: A function that determines the filtered options to be rendered on search, in our case we used it to add selectAll checkbox.
- `renderOption`: Render the option, use getOptionLabel by default.
- `renderInput`: To render the input,
- `onChange`: Callback fired when the value changes

Now you can play with selected values using `handleChange` so once the select is fired check if the selected option is select all if yes then set the newest `selectedOptions`

```js
<Autocomplete
      multiple
      disableCloseOnSelect
      options={items}
      value={selectedOptions}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
      filterOptions={(options, params) => {
        const filtered = filter(options, params)
        return [{ id: 0, name: selectAllLabel }, ...filtered]
      }}
      renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => {
        // To control the state of 'select-all' checkbox
        const selectAllProps =
          option.name === 'Sélectionner Tous' ? { checked: allSelected } : {}
        return (
          <li {...props}>
            <Checkbox checked={selected} {...selectAllProps} />
            {option.name}
          </li>
        )
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label={label} placeholder={label} />
      )}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
```

you can refer to the [Autocomplete API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/) to get detailed definition of each item

You can refer to this codeSendBox to check a demo of [react material Autocomplete with select all using react material ui version 5 and react hook form verion 7](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-ui-autocomplete-select-all-3gegtq?file=/src/MultiSelect.js)

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

for React version 16.13.1 and later. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/popper-in-autocomplete-forked-5vd48?file=/src/Component.jsx)

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
const timer = useRef(-1);

const setOpenByTimer = (isOpen) => {
    clearTimeout(timer.current);
    timer.current = window.setTimeout(() => {
      setOpen(isOpen);
    }, 200);
}

const MyPopper = function (props) {
    const addAllClick = (e) => {
      clearTimeout(timer.current);
      console.log('Add All');
    }
    const clearClick = (e) => {
      clearTimeout(timer.current);
      console.log('Clear');
    }
    return (
      <Popper {...props}>
        <ButtonGroup color="primary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
          <Button color="primary" onClick={addAllClick}>
            Add All
          </Button>
          <Button color="primary" onClick={clearClick}>
            Clear
          </Button>
        </ButtonGroup>
        {props.children}
      </Popper>
    );
};
return (
    <Autocomplete
      PopperComponent={MyPopper}     
      onOpen={(e) => {
        console.log('onOpen');   
        setOpenByTimer(true);    
      }}
      onClose={(obj,reason) => {
        console.log('onClose', reason);
        setOpenByTimer(false);       
      }}
      open={open}  
      .....
      ....
    />
);
```

**Old Answer**

Just customise PopperComponent and do whatever you want.

[Autocomplete API](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/)

```
const addAllClick = (e: any) => {
    setValue(items);
};
const clearClick = (e: any) => {
    setValue([]);
};
const MyPopper = function (props: any) {
    return (
      <Popper {...props}>
        <ButtonGroup color="primary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
          <Button color="primary" onClick={addAllClick}>
            Add All
          </Button>
          <Button color="primary" onClick={clearClick}>
            Clear
          </Button>
        </ButtonGroup>      
        {props.children}
      </Popper>
    );
};
<Autocomplete
    PopperComponent={MyPopper}
    ...  
/>
```

Comment: the onClick event handler doesn't trigger the function addAllClick and clearClick. how to deal with it?

Comment: @Shoeb May be there is a different problem. Did you try like this? onClick={e => console.log('worked')}

Comment: Also have a look, I've used that here https://github.com/onka13/onka-react-libs/blob/master/admin/src/ui/panel/components/form/ReferenceComponent.tsx#L192

Comment: I tried. Could you please have a look at my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/popper-in-autocomplete-xqidi?file=/src/Component.jsx)?

Comment: @Shoeb I've updated my answer. Probably there's a config for it But I've solved it by managing open state. At least it's working well :)